# ES6 : optimizing the Command pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, command

I'm building a kind of in-browser CLI for doing tests on a Game Engine.

The app looks like a console, with an input test and a submit button below a results sequence container DIV.

Behind the scene, there is an Invoker and numerous Commands objects :

```
// imports
import Invoker from '../cli/Invoker.js'

import Command1 from '../commands/Command1.js'
import Command2 from '../commands/Command2.js'
// ...
import Command20 from '../commands/Command20.js'

// instanciatiing
const invoker = new Invoker(context)

const commands = [
  new Command1(),
  new Command2(),
  // ...
  new Command20(),
]

// attach in invoker
commands.forEach(command => invoker.install(command))
```

the usage is pretty simple :

```
// later...
invoker.run('command20', { ...withArgs })
```

QUESTION 1/2:

Since this creates a bunch of imports, and initialization code, which could over time pollute the namespace of the client app code. How to fix it ? Builder pattern ? Facade ? Flyweight ? or something other ?

QUESTION 2/2

Rendering results : couldn't figure exactly where to put the code which take the effects of running a command, render (either with Mustache or JSX) and append it to the resulting DIV. Some comments ?

Help is welcome. Regards.

Comment: are all your commands called commands? wouldn't it be better to give them good names and therefore this wouldn't be a problem or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: also, how would it . "pollute the namespace of the client app code" if its in its own module?

Comment: No and yes ! they have names like Init, RayCasts, Play, Revert, Help, Status, Cheat, ListCommands, etc... so that's it ! the idea is to group them inside a module, and expose the resulting invoker...

Comment: @Hefeust, you could use dynamic imports and store commands on a map...

Answer (score 0):

OK! the good answer is the Module Pattern. Not really one of the 23  GoF patterns, mostly a ES 2015 pattern. But no matters ! I still develop this way. Thanks !

For question 2/2 I intend to attach the render method to the resulting object -or- a render method per command bound to context after each command invocation...

[Considering this as SOLVED]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webpack's feature called context to do a bunch of imports

```
const files = require.context('.', false, /\.js$/);
const commands = {};

files.keys().forEach((key) => {
  if (key === './index.js') return;
  commands[key.replace(/(\.\/|\.js)/g, '')] = files(key).default;
});

export default commands;
```

and you can use namespaced as vuex

command1.js

```
export { actions: { get: {} }, namespaced: true }
```

app.js

```
context.dispatch('command1/get', param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning 2/2 you should go ahead and use Observer or PubSub.

Simply follow the modern days way and add a store to your project using redux/mobx (I prefer mobx for small/medium projects) or any other technology of your choice and push the changes to the store after the command execution. Handle the store changes as a separate process. If you're using React in can be done in no time.